# How do you resolve the 500 error "Navigator is not defined" when installing third-party plugins in a Nuxt 3 app?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am currently unable to use third-party plugins in my Nuxt 3 application. Here's what my code/setup looks like:

- In my `package.json` I have the following dependency: `"@braze/web-sdk": "^4.6.1"`
- In my `plugins/` directory, I have a `braze.client.js` file
- Within the `braze.client.js` file, I have the following:

```
import * as braze from '@braze/web-sdk'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  braze.initialize(apiKey, {
    baseUrl: apiEndpoint
  })
  return {
    provide: {
      openSession
    }
  }
})
```

- Within my `nuxt.config.ts`, I added the following (since my project has Vite, I followed Braze's documentation here: https://www.braze.com/docs/developer_guide/platform_integration_guides/web/initial_sdk_setup/#vite):

```
optimizeDeps: {
      exclude: ['@braze/web-sdk']
}
```

- Then within my `<script>` tags within the page/component, I have the following:

```
const { $openSession } = useNuxtApp()
onMounted(() => {
  $openSession()
})
```

All the steps above continue to create a "500 navigator is not defined" error and I'm stumped with how I can resolve it.

I tried using `beforeOnMount`, not using as lifecycle hook, as well as placing `$openSession()` within an if statement:

```
if (process.client) {
}
```

Yet no matter what, it still renders the 500 error.